# How to effectively sort or filter objects on a site page?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, sorting

I have an online store website written in django. I want to add sorting (and filters) to the product page by various parameters. How to do it effectively?

1) Store several databases already sorted (by date, by popularity, etc.).

2) Sort when prompted from the database.

Comment: One would require additional memory space on your hard drive and the other would require some CPU and RAM usage. Both would require that you write an adequate code that does the work. Your choice really

Comment: Of course, thanks for the answer! But the question was not which option to use, but which one was more effective. If we have a lot of objects.

Comment: We can't possibly know that for your specific use case, but I assume updating several different databases whenever one of the products need to change isn't the smart thing to do

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution is about using a cache system. You can differentiate which user is logged in and basing on his settings you can store already queried results